# concatenate several objects with the same name and index

Tags: javascript

listAnimal.json

```
[
0:
{
base: {address: 'address house 1', animal: 'DOG', name: 'boby'}
},
1:
{
base: {address: 'address house 2', animal: 'CAT', name: 'pippo'}
},

2:
{base: {address: 'address house 3', animal: 'TIGER', name: 'best'}
},
3:
{base: {address: 'address house 4', animal: 'HORSE', name: 'lino'}
},
]
```

otherInformation.json

```
[{
    "boby":
     { "id":1,
    "img":"link img dog",
    "forum":" link forum dog"
},

"pippo": 
     { "id":2,

    "img":"link img cat",
    "forum":" link forum cat"
},
"best":  
    { "id":3,
    "img":" link img tiger",
    "forum":" link forum tiger"
}, ]
```

good morning everyone,
i have these 2 json files which i can't concatenate as i want
let me explain better, the final result should be
that is, you have to join who has the same name and index

```
[
0:
{
base: {address: 'address house 1', animal: 'DOG', name: 'boby'}
"id":1,
"img":"link img dog",
"forum":" link forum dog"
},
etc
```

I have tried with several methods "Object.assign ()", "Object.concat ()
I add the objects in the array but as new indexes

Comment: ``otherInformation`` is not valid json

Comment: Actually, neither is valid JSON. If your files are like that, you cannot parse them as JSON.

Comment: OK, I had not noticed that. So reverted again to the very original post.

Comment: Seems best, looks like console logs not actual source, but OP can clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

```js
const info = [
  {
    "boby":
    {
      "id": 1,
      "img": "link img dog",
      "forum": " link forum dog"
    }
  },

  {
    "pippo":
    {
      "id": 2,

      "img": "link img cat",
      "forum": " link forum cat"
    }
  },
  {
    "best":
    {
      "id": 3,
      "img": " link img tiger",
      "forum": " link forum tiger"
    }
  },
]

const infoObj = Object.assign({}, ...info)

const animals = [

  {
    base: {
      address: 'address house 1',
      animal: 'DOG',
      name: 'boby'
    }
  },

  {
    base: {
      address: 'address house 2',
      animal: 'CAT',
      name: 'pippo'
    }
  },


  {
    base: {
      address: 'address house 3',
      animal: 'TIGER',
      name: 'best'
    }
  },

  {
    base: {
      address: 'address house 4',
      animal: 'HORSE',
      name: 'lino'
    }
  },
]

const result = animals.map(a => ({
 ...a,
 ...(infoObj[a.base.name] || {})
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: R4ncid thanks I solved with your lines